# Why does this C++ project fail to build even when appropriate .lib is linked in?

Tags: c++, gcc, build

I am attempting to build sample code from Actian Btrieve (https://docs.actian.com/psql/btrieve2v13/html/btest_8cpp-example.html)

It wouldn't build so I've simplified the code down to the following, just to get it working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "btrieveCpp.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   Btrieve::StatusCode status = Btrieve::STATUS_CODE_UNKNOWN;
   std::cout << Btrieve::MAXIMUM_RECORD_LENGTH << std::endl;
   //BtrieveFile btrieveFile;
   std::cout << "test" << std::endl << status;
   return 0;
}
```

That code builds and runs successfully.  Libraries are statically linked and the compiler finds the btrieveCpp.h header file because I've included in the search path.

The build command looks like hte following (the breaks are just so you can read it more easily):

```
    mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g 
-IC:\Dev\Actian\Zen-SDK-Btrieve2API-Windows-noarch-14.00.046.000\include -c 
C:\Dev\C++\Btrieve1\btest.cpp -o obj\Debug\btest.o

    mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Btrieve1.exe obj\Debug\btest.o  -static
```

**Program Output**

The program output looks like:

[image: program output]

**The Problem**

However, if I uncomment the BtrieveFile line then I get errors when I build, which looks like the following:

[image: build errors]

**Using Code::Blocks IDE**

I'm using the Code::Blocks IDE and when I right-click the BtrieveFile item and choose Find Declaration then the IDE takes me to the .H file so it knows where the item is defined.

[image: find definition]

Also, keep in mind that the other item (`Btrieve::MAXIMUM_RECORD_LENGTH`) is also defined there (btrieveCpp.h), but it builds with no errors.

Here's where it takes me in the .H file:

[image: btrieve file]

**What I've Tried**

I thought this was because it needed the defintions provided by the .lib file so I added the appropriate .lib so the linker would find it and statically link it in.

I added the lib file as a dependency:

[image: dependency link]

After that I attempted to build again but it still fails.

The build log looks like the following:  You can see that the .lib is being linked in now.

> -------- Build: Debug in Btrieve1 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------
>
> mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g
>   -IC:\Dev\Actian\Zen-SDK-Btrieve2API-Windows-noarch-14.00.046.000\include
>   -c C:\Dev\C++\Btrieve1\btest.cpp -o obj\Debug\btest.o
>   mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Debug\Btrieve1.exe obj\Debug\btest.o  **-static  C:\Dev\Actian\Zen-SDK-Btrieve2API-Windows-noarch-14.00.046.000\win32\x86\btrieveCpp.lib**
>   c:/devtools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   obj\Debug\btest.o: in function `main':
>   C:/Dev/C++/Btrieve1/btest.cpp:13: undefined reference to
>   'BtrieveFile::BtrieveFile()'
>   c:/devtools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   C:/Dev/C++/Btrieve1/btest.cpp:13: undefined reference to
>   'BtrieveFile::~BtrieveFile()'
>   c:/devtools/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   C://Dev/C++/Btrieve1/btest.cpp:13: undefined reference to
>   'BtrieveFile::~BtrieveFile()'
>   collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status
>   Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) 4
>   error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s))

Would you happen to know what I'm missing?  Or what I need to do to resolve this?

**EDIT - Changing Linkage**

In btrieveC.h (included by btrieveCpp.h) there is indeed a block like the following:

```
#ifndef LINKAGE
    #ifdef __GNUC__
        #define LINKAGE
    #else
        #define LINKAGE __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#endif
```

However, if make the switch so that `#define LINKAGE __declspec(dllimport)` is used and then build I see the following errors (below)

Notice that the names are mangled in output now?

[image: cdeclspec]

**Edit 2 - nm output of btrieveCpp.lib**

```
nm -C C:\Dev\Actian\Zen-SDK-Btrieve2API-Windows-noarch-14.00.046.000\win32\x86\btrieveCpp.lib | findstr /I BtrieveFile
00000000 T ??0BtrieveFile@@IAE@PAUbtrieve_file@@@Z
00000000 I _imp_??0BtrieveFile@@IAE@PAUbtrieve_file@@@Z
00000000 T ??0BtrieveFile@@QAE@XZ
00000000 I _imp_??0BtrieveFile@@QAE@XZ
00000000 T ??0BtrieveFileAttributes@@QAE@XZ
00000000 I _imp_??0BtrieveFileAttributes@@QAE@XZ
00000000 T ??0BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE@XZ
00000000 I _imp_??0BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE@XZ
00000000 T ??1BtrieveFile@@QAE@XZ
00000000 I _imp_??1BtrieveFile@@QAE@XZ
00000000 T ??1BtrieveFileAttributes@@QAE@XZ
00000000 I _imp_??1BtrieveFileAttributes@@QAE@XZ
00000000 T ??1BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE@XZ
00000000 I _imp_??1BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE@XZ
00000000 T ??4BtrieveFile@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z
00000000 I _imp_??4BtrieveFile@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z
00000000 T ??4BtrieveFileAttributes@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z
00000000 I _imp_??4BtrieveFileAttributes@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z
00000000 T ??4BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z
00000000 I _imp_??4BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z
00000000 T ?BulkCreate@BtrieveFile@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveBulkCreatePayload@@PAVBtrieveBulkCreateResult@@@Z
00000000 I _imp_?BulkCreate@BtrieveFile@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveBulkCreatePayload@@PAVBtrieveBulkCreateResult@@@Z
00000000 T ?BulkRetrieveNext@BtrieveFile@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveBulkRetrieveAttributes@@PAVBtrieveBulkRetrieveResult@@W4LockMode@3@@Z
00000000 I _imp_?BulkRetrieveNext@BtrieveFile@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveBulkRetrieveAttributes@@PAVBtrieveBulkRetrieveResult@@W4LockMode@3@@Z
00000000 T ?BulkRetrievePrevious@BtrieveFile@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveBulkRetrieveAttributes@@PAVBtrieveBulkRetrieveResult@@W4LockMode@3@@Z
00000000 I _imp_?BulkRetrievePrevious@BtrieveFile@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveBulkRetrieveAttributes@@PAVBtrieveBulkRetrieveResult@@W4LockMode@3@@Z
00000000 T ?FileClose@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFile@@@Z
00000000 I _imp_?FileClose@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFile@@@Z
00000000 T ?FileCreate@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFileAttributes@@PAVBtrieveIndexAttributes@@PBDW4CreateMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 I _imp_?FileCreate@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFileAttributes@@PAVBtrieveIndexAttributes@@PBDW4CreateMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 T ?FileCreate@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFileAttributes@@PAVBtrieveIndexAttributes@@PB_WW4CreateMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 I _imp_?FileCreate@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFileAttributes@@PAVBtrieveIndexAttributes@@PB_WW4CreateMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 T ?FileCreate@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFileAttributes@@PBDW4CreateMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 I _imp_?FileCreate@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFileAttributes@@PBDW4CreateMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 T ?FileCreate@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFileAttributes@@PB_WW4CreateMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 I _imp_?FileCreate@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFileAttributes@@PB_WW4CreateMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 T ?FileOpen@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFile@@PBD1W4OpenMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 I _imp_?FileOpen@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFile@@PBD1W4OpenMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 T ?FileOpen@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFile@@PB_WPBDW4OpenMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 I _imp_?FileOpen@BtrieveClient@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PAVBtrieveFile@@PB_WPBDW4OpenMode@3@W4LocationMode@3@@Z
00000000 T ?GetBalancedIndexes@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetBalancedIndexes@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 T ?GetBtrieveFile@BtrieveCollection@@IAEPAVBtrieveFile@@XZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetBtrieveFile@BtrieveCollection@@IAEPAVBtrieveFile@@XZ
00000000 T ?GetBtrieveFile@BtrieveFile@@IAEPAUbtrieve_file@@XZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetBtrieveFile@BtrieveFile@@IAEPAUbtrieve_file@@XZ
00000000 T ?GetBtrieveFileAttributes@BtrieveFileAttributes@@IAEPAUbtrieve_file_attributes@@XZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetBtrieveFileAttributes@BtrieveFileAttributes@@IAEPAUbtrieve_file_attributes@@XZ
00000000 T ?GetBtrieveFileInformation@BtrieveFileInformation@@IAEPAUbtrieve_file_information@@XZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetBtrieveFileInformation@BtrieveFileInformation@@IAEPAUbtrieve_file_information@@XZ
00000000 T ?GetBtrieveFilePtr@BtrieveFile@@IAEPAPAUbtrieve_file@@XZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetBtrieveFilePtr@BtrieveFile@@IAEPAPAUbtrieve_file@@XZ
00000000 T ?GetClientTransactions@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetClientTransactions@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 T ?GetContinuousOperation@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetContinuousOperation@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 T ?GetCursorPosition@BtrieveFile@@QAE_JXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetCursorPosition@BtrieveFile@@QAE_JXZ
00000000 T ?GetDuplicateRecordConflictCursorPosition@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE_JXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetDuplicateRecordConflictCursorPosition@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE_JXZ
00000000 T ?GetDuplicateRecordConflictIndex@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE?AW4Index@Btrieve@@XZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetDuplicateRecordConflictIndex@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE?AW4Index@Btrieve@@XZ
00000000 T ?GetExplicitLocks@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetExplicitLocks@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 T ?GetFileVersion@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE?AW4FileVersion@Btrieve@@XZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetFileVersion@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE?AW4FileVersion@Btrieve@@XZ
00000000 T ?GetFixedRecordLength@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetFixedRecordLength@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 T ?GetFreeSpaceThreshold@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE?AW4FreeSpaceThreshold@Btrieve@@XZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetFreeSpaceThreshold@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE?AW4FreeSpaceThreshold@Btrieve@@XZ
00000000 T ?GetGatewayMajorVersion@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetGatewayMajorVersion@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 T ?GetGatewayMinorVersion@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetGatewayMinorVersion@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 T ?GetGatewayName@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PADH@Z
00000000 I _imp_?GetGatewayName@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAE?AW4StatusCode@Btrieve@@PADH@Z
00000000 T ?GetGatewayName@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEPBDXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetGatewayName@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEPBDXZ
00000000 T ?GetGatewayPatchLevel@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetGatewayPatchLevel@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 T ?GetGatewayPlatform@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 I _imp_?GetGatewayPlatform@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
00000000 T ?GetHandleCount@BtrieveFileInformation@@QAEHXZ
```

Comment: *Your build command doesn't link any library*. Also, notice the red warning in your IDE screen: "This project uses build scripts so it may override any options you set here".

Comment: At a guess: `btrieveCpp.lib` was compiled with a different compiler and the name mangling is wrong for mingw.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen doesn't the build log show that the lib is included with  -static C:\Dev\Actian\Zen-SDK-Btrieve2API-Windows-noarch-14.00.046.000\win32\x86\btrieveCpp.lib?

Comment: @Botje Isn't that what the LINKAGE def is for -- It is defined in btrieveC.h like:
#ifndef LINKAGE
 #ifdef __GNUC__
  #define LINKAGE
 #else
  #define LINKAGE __declspec(dllimport)
 #endif
#endif

Comment: No. Please inspect the defined symbols in the `.lib` file and compare them to the needed symbols in your `.o` file. `nm` and/or `dumpbin` should be able to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I note the class declaration has: `class LINKAGE BtrieveFile`. Is the symbol `LINKAGE` defined properly in your build -- should probably become `__declspec(import)` (cf. [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/declspec?view=vs-2019)) since you're using Windows libraries, even though you're building with gcc via mingw.

There is probably a block in Btrieve's headers that has `ifdef`s for that. Find that, define the right symbol project-wide, and you should then get the symbols imported properly. Then you'll just need to make sure the DLL is in your EXE's directory or the search path in order to run the EXE.

---

Update:

Alas, your new issues probably show that you can't do what you want because the library was built with a different compiler. See [MinGW's Interoperability of Libraries Created by Different Compiler Brands](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Interoperability_of_Libraries_Created_by_Different_Compiler_Brands). You probably need to use the same compiler (or at least a compatible one) that the library was built with, OR you need to get a version of the library built with GCC (or build it yourself, if that's an option). There is a free community edition of Visual Studio, if that helps.

Comment: I tried this and updated my question above (see last section).  It seems like the names get mangled but it still fails.  I may have done something incorrectly still though.  Wait...I just saw the edit about the DLLs. Will do that also, that is probably the problem.

Comment: Did you get the output from `nm` or `dumpbin` ? If so can you add that to the question. I think it could help your question get an answer.

Comment: @drescherjm I ran nm through findstr and output some of the details since there is so much in the lib file.

Comment: @metal I actually tried building with Visual Studio too but it failed.  However, now that I better understand the name mangling thing, I will go back and try setting it up and seeing if I can get it to work.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, I finally got this working under Visual Studio so I will mark this as the correct answer -- Must use the same compiler as was used to build the LIB.  Thanks!